# How to extract elements from JSON File with python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the JSON file below and i am trying to extract the value `dob_year` from each item if the name element is `jim`.

This is my try:

```
import json

with open('j.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    if data['name'] == 'jim'
        print(data['dob_year'])
```

Error:

```
File "extractjson.py", line 6 if data['name'] == 'jim' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is my file.

```
[
      {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "10",
        "sex": "male",
        "dob_year": "2007",
        "ssn": "123-23-1234"
      },
      {
        "name": "jill",
        "age": "6",
        "sex": "female",
        "dob_year": "2011",
        "ssn": "123-23-1235"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Your data is a list of dictionaries. You need to loop through `(d['dob_year'] for d in data if d['name'] == 'jim')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list in the JSON file

```
data = json.load(json_file)
for item in data:
    if item['name'] == 'jim':
        print(item['dob_year'])
```

Comment: i am getting the error: `File "extractjson.py", line 6 if data['name'] == 'jim' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list of dictionaries! you cannot directly access the key value pairs.
Try encapsulating it in a loop to check every dict in the list:

```py
import json

with open('j.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for set in data:
        if set['name'] == 'jim':
            print(set['dob_year'])
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `File "extractjson.py", line 6
    if set['name'] == 'jim'
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: ah yes i forgot the colon at the end, that line should be `if set['name'] == 'jim':`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import json

with open('j.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print([item["dob_year"] for item in a if item["name"] == "jim"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json.load()
```

returns a list of entries, the way you have saved it. You have to iterate through all list items, then search for your field in the list item.
Also, if it is a repetitive task, make a function out of it. You can pass different files, fields to be extracted, etc. this way, and it can make your job easier.

Example:

```
def extract_info(search_field, extract_field, name, filename):

import json

with open(filename) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for item in data:
        if item[search_field] == name:
            print(item[extract_field])

extract_info('name','dob_year','jim','j.json')
```